# Laravel trying to output posts but Controller function seem to work wrong

Tags: php, mysql, routes, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to output my posts and for that in a specific page I call a function with foreach to load all the posts, and the function in my controller is something like:

```
public function getDashboard()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('dashboard', ['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

and my route is something like this:

```
Route::get('/dashboard',[
    'uses' => 'PostController@getDashboard',
    'as' => 'dashboard'

]);
```

but get an error when I try to load the page when i'm not logged in
the error is something like:
**Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\wamp64\www\projectname\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php)**

Anything you say is highly appreciated.

(I use Laravel 5.3.26 )

Here you go this is my blade, but I don't think this is where the problem is:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
 @section('content')
  @foreach($posts as $post)
    <article class="post">
        <div class="media w3-border-left w3-border-blue">
            <div class="media-left media-top">

            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <header><h4 class="media-heading">{{ $post->title }}</h4></header>
                <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>
                <div class="info">
                    Posted by {{ $post->user->name }} on {{ $post->created_at }}
                </div>
                <div class="interaction">
                    <a href="#" class="like">Like</a> |
                    <a href="#" class="like">Dislike</a> |
                    <a href="#" class="like">Edit</a> |
                    <a href="#" class="like">Delete</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    </article>
  @endforeach
 @endsection
```

Comment: check $posts is empty or not

Comment: @VinodVT no it isn't It works properly when I login.

Comment: can you post your blade file - I think the problem is there

Comment: Change Route::get to Route::post. :)

Comment: Did that solve the issue?

Comment: @Rahi Now it gives the error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218

Comment: Did you check the page containing the form is doing the POST rather GET?

Comment: It does get, but to try what you said i switched it to post with my route and it gave the error I wrote

Comment: Do you get anything when you do var_dump($posts) in getDashboard() function?

Comment: @Rahi I dont even know how I supposed to use that :D but I assume it is used to see if I'm able to acces my database or not if so I'm able to post my whatever in my database properly when I login

Comment: @Rahi ok I think I figured out what you say. and i tried it and get tons of stuff, not sure if I should share all these. there are info about routes and everything

Comment: @AgilAsadi thanks, you're right. Couldn't be sure til I#d seen it though.  You only get the error when not logged in? I think your auth code is redirecting back to that blade without the data, let me try a solution for you. I''l post in a moment

Comment: yeap excactly, I get the error if only I'm not logged in

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public function getDashboard()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('dashboard', compact('posts'));
}
```

Comment: well as I said that works too, but if only I'm logged in, when I log out it gives the same error: Undefined variable: posts

Comment: when you logged out and hitting the same route you are getting error. at that point you should redirect to login page. have you manged that scenarion?

Comment: yeap, I'm able to route to the login page but that is not what I want, I wish to redirect to a page which includes posts ordered by specific rates which is the dashboard. I'm also able to redirect to dashboard if only it doesnt have the foreach part which includes the variable "posts"

Comment: Can you please do some hit and try like var_dump($posts) or remove all variable code and just try to run plain html, so that we can find out if route and all is working fine.

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\projectName\app\Http\Controllers\PostController.php:15:string ' posts' (length=6). is that what i supposed to get?

Comment: OK I see things :D but I dont know if it is safe to share all these?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it's your authentication redirecting to a different controller method (which is not injecting the Posts).

Try a composer in your routes\web.php

```
View::composer( ['dashboard.blade'] , function($view) {
   $action = app('request')->route()->getAction();
    dump($action);
    return $view->with(
        [
            'posts' => Post::all(), // you may need the fully qualified namespace here
        ]
    );
});
```

This is a bit dirty and you won't want to keep this but it should give you some further info to go off - if you can post the output of the dump and check that posts are still injected when logged out;

Using this method the output of my dump was

```
array:7 [▼
  "middleware" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "web"
    1 => "auth"
  ]
  "uses" => "App\Http\Controllers\Admin\TestController@home"
  "controller" => "App\Http\Controllers\Admin\TestController@home"
  "namespace" => "App\Http\Controllers\Admin"
  "prefix" => "/admin"
  "where" => []
  "as" => "admin.test"
]
```

Comment: It's a bit buggy, I tried to fix it but there seem to be some syntax problems, can you take a look? I closed 'posts' => Post:all(), with a ";" that is not it also added the correct bracked after (['dashboard.blade']

Comment: and also I added "::" after Post

Comment: @AgilAsadi I just put this into my app to test it and it works (I had to change the model to fit my app but other than that)

Comment: @AgilAsadi also I chaged the dump - it should give you more info